# Cant figure out right queryset for json in django

Tags: python, json, django, django-views, django-queryset

i need a help to get django query where my json file should get this data as output. I tried many ways but im getting it in bits and not completely. I'm new to Django and stuck with this for long. Please help. Thanks:)

```
[{
  "Group": "Mars",
  "count": 10,
  "Months": "June"
}, {
  "Group": "Jupiter",
  "count": 50,
  "Months": "June"
}, {
  "Group": "Mars",
  "count": 70,
  "Months": "July"
}, {
  "Group": "Jupiter",
  "count": 60,
  "Months": "July"
}, {
  "Group": "Mars",
  "count": 30,
  "Months": "August"
}, {
  "Group": "Jupiter",
  "count": 40,
  "Months": "August"
}];
```

I have possibly tried to get count of mars and jupiter in my views.py as follows which gives json as `[{'Group':'Mars','count':10},{'Group':'Jupiter','count':50}]` now months is added which is what im not getting and 'months' is in charfield.

views.py

```
fm_ds=Details.objects.filter(Group='Jupiter',Div='Cross',Shift='Day').count()
    m_ds=Details.objects.filter(Group='Mars',Div='Cross',Shift='Night').count()
    Jupiter_dict={}
    Jupiter_dict['Group']='Jupiter'
    Jupiter_dict['count']=fm_ds
    Mars_dict={}
    Mars_dict['Group']='Mars'
    Mars_dict['count']=m_ds
    print Jupiter_dict
    print Mars_dict
    details_dict=[Mars_dict,Jupiter_dict]
context = {'data_json': json.dumps(details_dict)}
```

models.py is

```
class Details(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Div=models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    Group =models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    Shift =models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    Months=models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True, default=None)
```

Comment: The "count" is the total for a specific group **in** a specific month?

Comment: Yes it is the count of people in specific group that work for day/night shift! @ThiagoRossener

Comment: Could you show your models?

Comment: @zaidfazil my model is added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with `annotate` function, like,

```
Details.objects.values('Group', 'months').annotate(count=Count('Group')).order_by('months')
```

Output would be,

```
<QuerySet [{'count': 5, 'months': 'December', 'Group': 'group1'},
    {'count': 3, 'months': 'December', 'Group': 'group3'},
    {'count': 10, 'months': 'June', 'Group': 'group1'}, 
    {'count': 10, 'months': 'May', 'Group': 'group1'}, 
    {'count': 6, 'months': 'May', 'Group': 'group3'}]>
```

Count would be the number of people in a group for a specific month, regardless of the `Shift` they work.

Hope, this is what you were looking for,

Comment: i want them in regard to the Shift also. Like Group 'Jupiter' working in day shift..count is 50 in month june, 60 in july & 40 in august. Could you please help me out with this?! @zaidfazil

Comment: Data should print exactly the same way my json appears! Mars and jupiter for month june. Mars and jupiter for month july and so on

Comment: You could just add an `order_by` clause, there for that.

Comment: Thanks:) got it!:)

Comment: Would you please do me a favour and tag the answer as selected, then?